# Java Multiple json names for same object field during serialisation

Tags: java, json, jackson

For serialising a java object's name field in json, if I have a java class:

```
Class Test {
  private String name;

}
```

When I create the Test object with a name.

In scenario one, when I serialise the test object, I would like the name field to be represented as name.

```
{ "name": "Bob"}
```

In scenario two , when I serialise the test object, I would like the name field to be represented as firstName.

```
{ "firstName": "Bob"}
```

How can I achieve this with jackson.

Thanks

Comment: Jackson view or custom serializer?

Answer (score 2):

You can user Views.

**Views**

```java
public class Views {

    public static class Foo {
    }

    public static class Bar {
    }
}
```

**DTO**

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

public class User {
    @JsonView(Views.Foo.class)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Bar.class)
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.name = this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```java
class JacksonViewTest {

    @Test
    void viewFoo() throws IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("John");
        user.setLastName("Doe");

        String json = new ObjectMapper()
                .writerWithView(Views.Foo.class)
                .writeValueAsString(user);

        assertSame("{\"name\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"}", json);
    }

    @Test
    void viewBar() throws IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("John");
        user.setLastName("Doe");

        String json = new ObjectMapper()
                .writerWithView(Views.Bar.class)
                .writeValueAsString(user);

        assertSame("{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"}", json);
    }

}
```